# Passing custom classes in COM C++

Tags: c++, com

If I am making a COM dll and using MIDL to define an interface for COM, how would I pass an instance of a custom class to a function in that dll?

for example if I have defined this in IDL, I cannot pass a CustomObject*, how instead would I be able to pass an instance of CustomObject?

```
[
   //idl junk
]
IMyComService{
    [id(1)]HRESULT Foo([in] CustomObject* myObject); //Error
}
```

In this setup the COM dll has the header file which defines "CustomObject" and the application which is calling the dll is referencing the header file and creating the instance of "CustomObject" and CustomObject is any arbitrary class with functions and properties not necessarily using only Microsoft types.

Comment: You define an interface, and make your `CustomObject` implement that interface. Your `Foo` function receives a pointer to the interface.

Comment: You just can't, implementation is very carefully hidden in COM, you can only ever work with interfaces.  Why you think you have to pass an implementation reference is not clear, whatever underlying class that implements the interface should know it.

Comment: @IInspectable will this work even if the ICustomObject interface doesn't define a COM object? (implementing IUnknown etc...) or should all classes in the COM dll be COM classes?

Comment: If your DLL is exposing non-COM API for some things (such as creating instances of `CustomObject` class), what's the point of using COM for other things? It makes no sense to mix and match - either use COM all the way, or not at all.

Comment: As soon as you start mixing non-COM classes into your COM interfaces, COM stops being COM. Among other things, MIDL can no longer generate marshaling code, and you are left with implementing your own marshalers. You aren't saving yourself any work by introducing non-COM classes into your COM interfaces, and if you do it's not immediately obvious, why you chose COM to begin with.